# How can I use Image flow in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, imageresizer

I use tthis example to crop images and cash images but the performance is bad
https://www.paddo.org/asp-net-core-image-resizing-middleware/

here is the link to modify image and get image from cash

http://jsc-krm.ps/Data/Images/2271a0ba-c400-4ed6-91cc-10f29c663dbc.jpg?w=1280&h=755&mode=crop&scale=both

the origin image
http://jsc-krm.ps/Data/Images/2271a0ba-c400-4ed6-91cc-10f29c663dbc.jpg

the origin image is very faster than the image with attribute

I need Image resizer asp.net core with cash high performance and how to use it

Answer (score 2):

For image operations I definitely recommend [net-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips) library which includes .NET bindings for the high performance libvips C library.

Answer (score 0):

The successor to ImageResizer is [Imageflow.NET](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet). The .NET Core middleware is [Imageflow.NET Server](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server). Imageflow outperforms libvips on jpegs and produces higher quality images (it combines adaptive subsampling with the mozjpeg library).